# ruby ide : starting iruby throws error

Tags: ruby

I installed gem install iruby
but then i cant start it. heres the error it throws
could somebody point out whats the problem?

```
:~$ iruby
Creating profile directory /home/userme/.config/iruby/profile_default
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/iruby-0.1.7/lib/iruby/command.rb:75:in `symlink': No such file or directory @ sys_fail2 - (/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/iruby-0.1.7/lib/iruby/static, /h
ome/akurnya/.config/iruby/profile_default/static) (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/iruby-0.1.7/lib/iruby/command.rb:75:in `create_profile'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/iruby-0.1.7/lib/iruby/command.rb:46:in `run_ipython'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/iruby-0.1.7/lib/iruby/command.rb:17:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/iruby-0.1.7/bin/iruby:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
```

is this a symlink problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem in the end? I'm experiencing the exact same issue. IPython is installed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240541/error-installing-iruby-gem?noredirect=1#comment41173167_26240541

Answer (score -1):

You must install IPython. IRuby is only a kernel for IPython.

Answer (score -1):

To answer my questions,
I installed ipython's latest version which iruby demands (v >2.x)
and followed instructions [here](https://github.com/minad/iruby)

That seemed to work;

Comment: I want to ask the downvoter the reason for his downvote

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: ill get back to this and paste the description after a while