# Error Installing iruby gem

Tags: ruby, ipython, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am attempting to install and [run iruby](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/minad/iruby/blob/master/IRuby-Example.ipynb). 
 I run iruby in the terminal with `iruby` but I receive:

```
iruby notebook
/Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/iruby-0.1.13/lib/iruby/command.rb:38:in ``': No such file or directory - ipython (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/iruby-0.1.13/lib/iruby/command.rb:38:in `check_version'
    from /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/iruby-0.1.13/lib/iruby/command.rb:46:in `run_ipython'
    from /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/iruby-0.1.13/lib/iruby/command.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/iruby-0.1.13/bin/iruby:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/iruby:23:in `load'
    from /Users/jona/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/iruby:23:in `<main>'
```

I have [installed ipython](http://ipython.org/install.html) ( I have installed Anaconda, but when i

```
run conda update conda
```

and

```
conda update ipython
```

but says:

```
command not found: conda
```

Is this an iruby program issue?

Comment: It looks like it can't find either ipython or conda. Check that the directory containing those commands (possibly `/Users/jona/anaconda/bin`, depending on where you installed Anaconda), is in your `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @ThomasK I moved the anaconda folder to /Users/jona/. i run the conda commands but same issue.

Comment: The installation probably added the install location to `$PATH`, and when you moved it, you broke that. You'll need to manually change your `$PATH` environment variable to include the new location of Anaconda.

Comment: I only moved the location after you commented on it... I'm not familiar with environment variables. I'm researching it put I cannot fix it still... I did go to the Anaconda GUI launcher and updated iPython. I was able to launch it.

Comment: Look for a file in your home directory called something like `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. These are hidden by default, so you may have to do something extra to see them. Add a line to the file you find like `PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`. Then close your terminal and reopen it, and you should be able to run `ipython`  and `conda`. You can use the command `echo $PATH` to see the contents of PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

The trouble was that the Anaconda `.../bin` directory was not on `$PATH`, so the commands `ipython` and `conda` could not be found.

To fix this: Look for a file in your home directory called something like `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. These are hidden by default, so you may have to do something extra to see them. Add a line to the file you find like `PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`. Then close your terminal and reopen it, and you should be able to run ipython and conda. You can use the command `echo $PATH` to see the contents of PATH.